# react UI doesn't not update after code edit

Tags: reactjs, github, next.js, react-state, smooth-scrolling

I am working on an already existing project you can check the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/studio-freight/lenis/tree/main/website)

The goal is to convert the hard-coded data in the image below to an API called data, but this isn't the problem right now :

[image]

the problem I'm facing is, after cloning the repository and running it locally, any modification I apply to the code isn't showing on the UI, per example, if I change "LENIS BRING THE HEAT" in the image above in this sample of code

```
<aside className={s.title}>
         <p className="h3">
           <AppearTitle>
             Lenis brings
             <br />
             <span className="grey">the shit</span>
           </AppearTitle>
         </p>
       </aside>
```

to "LENIS BRINGS SOMETHING", the text remains the same in the UI :

```
<aside className={s.title}>
          <p className="h3">
            <AppearTitle>
              Lenis brings
              <br />
              <span className="grey">something</span>
            </AppearTitle>
          </p>
        </aside>
```

this applies to everything else, no matter how much i change the code, the UI won't change at all.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, maybe a cloning bug, or I'm just missing something

Comment: If you are using the Chrome browser, there's an option in the DevTools  for "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" that might solve some issues. Cache can happen even on localhost. You can also force a full reload by doing `Crtl-F5` in the browser window (in most browsers).

Comment: didn't work unfortunately

Comment: What editor/IDE are you using? Some editors publish the files to a different location for localhost than the source files, so you may not see changes correctly if you are pointing your browser to the source files instead of the published files. Sorry if that sounds super basic, but I'm just trying to cover all the bases.